# IS it possible to open a *.sln file created using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 in MS VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have a workspace (*.sln, *.vcproj) files which are created using MS VS 2008 edition. Is tehre any way to convert them to open in MS VS 2005 edition.

I have some errors in creating a new workspace with the source/header files. Because it has some resource files, included, some dll included. So assuming this option is ruled out, then are there any work arounds?

-AD.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to convert  MS VS2008 workspace files to MS VS 2005. I opened the *.sln in a text editor and manually changed the entry

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00 to version 9.0

Similar thing i edited in *.vcproj file. 
in *.vcproj file the actual entry says:

```
VisualStudioProject

    ProjectType="Visual C++"

    Version="9.00"
```

which i changed to version 8.00.

After these changes i am able to open the same workspace in MS VS 2005.

Cool!

-AD

Comment: Many solution/project files only need a version bump between 2005 -> 2008 due to the fact that 2008 fully supports .NET 2.0. Smart move on Microsoft's part. But the reverse isn't necessarily true, you might not be able to bump the version down all the time. Glad to hear it worked for you though :)

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to change the version number in the files, they are just normal XML files...

Your milage may vary about actually getting those to open though. Unless you have alot of metadata files (.sln, .vcproj, etc), it may just be easier to recreate a new set of solution/project files in VS2005

Answer (score 0):

You could create an new solution and and add the projects in 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the money you save by not upgrading your VS2005 to VS2008 would easily pay for the time and potential errors in the reverse conversion process. Ask yourself - is it worth the risk and mucking around?

Answer (score 0):

Open .sln fine in notepad change "Visual Studio 2008" to "Visual Studio 2005" ( mostly in 2nd or 3rd line) and save. After this solution can be opened in Vs2005, you might get some errors. 
Note: To compile VS2008 solution in VS2005 you need to remove all .Net 3.0 and 3.5 references and code  from solution.